# Delete dropdown list from list of dropdown lists in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dropdown

I have this code from geeksforgeeks that I modified. The original code would add and delete from a list of textareas. I tried to do the same with dropdown lists. But, it does not work as expected. The changes I would like to make are:

1. On pressing the "Add item" button, the drop down list should be added below the previous one.
2. On clicking the "Remove item" button, the bottom most drop down list should be removed.

Here is the link to my current code:
https://jsfiddle.net/coderr/dq12vL4j/

HTML

```
<ul id="list"></ul>
 
    <input type="text" id="candidate" />
    <button onclick="addItem()" class="buttonClass">
    Add item</button>
    <button onclick="removeItem()" class="buttonClass">
    Remove item</button>
```

Javascript

```
var myParent = document.body;

//Create array of options to be added
var array = ["Volvo","Saab","Mercades","Audi"];

//Create and append select list
function addItem() {
var selectList = document.createElement("select");
selectList.id = "mySelect";
myParent.appendChild(selectList);

//Create and append the options
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = array[i];
    option.text = array[i];
    selectList.appendChild(option);
}
}
        // Creating a function to remove item from list
        function removeItem() {

            // Declaring a variable to get select element
            var a = document.getElementById("list");
            var candidate = document.getElementById("candidate");
            var item = document.getElementById(candidate.value);
            a.removeChild(item);
        }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed the `removeItem()` function so now it removes the last child of the div which contains all the drop down lists. Also added a `display: block;` to the div to

```js
const list = document.getElementById('list')
var myParent = document.body

//Create array of options to be added
var array = ['Volvo', 'Saab', 'Mercades', 'Audi']

//Create and append select list
function addItem() {
  var selectList = document.createElement('select')
  selectList.id = 'mySelect'
  selectList.style.display = 'block'
  myParent.appendChild(selectList)

  //Create and append the options
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement('option')
    option.value = array[i]
    option.text = array[i]
    selectList.appendChild(option)
  }
  list.appendChild(selectList)
}

// Creating a function to remove item from list
function removeItem() {
  list.lastChild?.remove()
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="candidate" />
<button onclick="addItem()" class="buttonClass">Add item</button>
<button onclick="removeItem()" class="buttonClass">Remove item</button>
<div id="list"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked. How can I change the first text area into a drop down list as well?

Comment: @usr18 You can replace `<input type="text" id="candidate" />` with a select element `<select name="" id=""></select>` and add options to it [see here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp).

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much!!